# Use a smartphone as a Dial Up Modem?

Tags: networking, modem, dial-up, smartphone

Most cellphones today have an audio jack that works as both output and input for sound. That's why there's headphones today with built in microphones for making phone calls. Now then, is it possible, using this two way audio jack, to make a dial up connection from my PC (using a software modem) through my phone?

Comment: Most phones actually have a serial port accessible over USB that has the same interface as a serial modem and long ago this was used with laptops to access the internet via dial up.

Comment: Someone can call me out on this, but I'm fairly sure the data being send over dial up connection is more than just audio.

Comment: @Moses How do you mean? The data is converted to analogue so it can be sent over a connection that is normally used for just audio.

Comment: @Moses POTs can only transmit audio.

Comment: @DanD. Didn't these phones still go onto a dial-up modem? As Moses said, I think more than just audio is sent over the line. The real question is why are you trying to use new tech to enable really, really old tech? Surely there's a better tethering solution than aiming for dial-up.

Comment: It is a good technical question, I think, but why do you need it today? Is it only way your computer can be connected to Internet?

Comment: Tethering would make more sense.

Comment: The purpose of this is basically for emergency use or when there's no wifi/4G signals available. I also don't have a tethering plan for my phone. So that's why I'd like to be able to access the internet anytime and anywhere I want, even if it's dialup through my phone. Usually everywhere I go still has phone service, but not necessarily internet. I also have an unlimited calling plan.

Comment: Well I'm actually using a Nokia Lumia 928 Windows Phone so I can't really root it to tether. There is a tethering app available on Windows Phone but it has its limits and sometimes in the city the network could get congested.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

No. Analog telephone modems (a.k.a. POTS - "Plain Old Telephone Service" modems) worked because when the traditional telephone network (a.k.a the PSTN - "Public Switched Telephone Network") digitized the audio, it did so with 8-bit samples 8,000 times per second, for a total of 8 bits * 8 kHz = 64,000 bps digital audio. It wasn't possible to fully utilize that full 64kbps for data because of problems with the analog <-> digital conversion (ADC/DAC), but if you had a digital modem on a digital phone line (like an ISDN B-channel), you could send at 53-56kbps through a single DAC. But from the analog line, you could only send 33.8kbps through a single ADC.

But the problem with cell phones is that they've never provided a full 64kbps digital audio channel like the landline PSTN did. They use lossy codecs to compress your voice audio down to fit into a 9600 bps channel. So if you want to try to do audio-modulated signaling over that channel, I think you'd be lucky to get 4800 bps (4.8kbps = 0.6 KibiBytes/sec) out of it. And that's assuming you design custom modulation schemes to get the most out of what that audio channel gives you. I have no idea if any of the traditional modulation schemes used by POTS modems would work well over GSM voice channels. For all I know, an off the shelf POTS modem may just completely fall on its face and not even be able to sustain the ages-old 300 bps rate over a GSM voice channel.

Update: I found a reference online that said that doing analog audio modulation over GSM voice channels was typically limited to 2400 bps, so my estimate above was quite generous.

---

This goes a little outside the scope of your question, but note that technologies existed to make dialup-like connections over digital cellular networks but without the severely rate-limiting analog complication of hooking a POTS modem to the headset jack of the cell phone.

One solution was called "Circuit-Switched Data" or CSD, and usually involved hooking your computer to your cell phone via a serial connection of some type (using traditional RS-232 or RS-422 style serial interfaces or IrDA in the old days, and USB or Bluetooth more recently), and having your cell phone give that serial interface direct access to the 9600 bps data connection to the wireless carrier's equipment. Inside the wireless carrier's network, your 9600 bps data stream would be fed into a digital modem hooked up to a digital phone line, so you could use this technology to make a 9600 bps modem call to any modem on the PSTN.

CSD was followed by High-Speed CSD (HSCSD), which was like CSD except your cell phone would use 4 GSM voice channels simultaneously, so you'd be able to make ~56kbps connections, just like (in the downstream channel at least) the last era of POTS modems (V.90).

Over digital cellular technologies like GPRS and EDGE, it was possible to use that serial connection to the phone to do PPP, but that wouldn't have worked to just any modem hooked up to any phone line; the other end of your PPP connection would need to be a PPP server that receives  its PPP connections not from modems, but over IP, tunneled in L2TP. This was common among ISPs that outsourced their dial-up modem POPs to third parties like Level 3 and UUNet, and is still common today among DSL ISPs (that's why so many DSL services require PPPoA or PPPoE).

---

**tl;dr:** To answer your specific question, No, it is probably not possible to hook a POTS modem via headset jack to a cell phone and make a successful connection to a modem on the PSTN. If it connects at all, it will probably only use extremely low data rates (even as POTS modems go), and be glitchy and unreliable. However, there are (or have been) other ways to connect a computer to a cell phone to make dial-up modem calls or PPP connections.

Comment: This is a problem for analog faxes on digital phone lines as well

Comment: VoIP uses a similar behavior where if a few bits are off it just doesn't and raises it hands :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. @Spiff starts saying "No", then goes on to explain how it actually can be possible, even though highly difficult to implement and getting a very low bandwidth. Right? ...

Comment: @msb I see my Answer as basically a No, but it's a *qualified* No. :-)

Comment: @Keltari: That's why GSM has a Fax protocol too, besides Voice and CSD ;). GSM was truly designed as a digital network, with the intent to do more than just voice.

Comment: Could I theoretically use a combination of these:

http://www.showmecables.com/product/iPhone-Telephone-Adapter-3-5mm-TRRS-Jack-to-RJ11-Plug-6-IN.aspx?utm_source=msn&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=(roi)+product+listing+ads&utm_term=23-108-005&zmam=49733141&zmac=6&zmas=1&zmap=23-108-005

http://www.ebay.com/itm/PC-Headset-to-Smart-phone-Adapter-Dual-3-5mm-to-3-5mm-New-/321265800257?pt=US_Audio_Cables_Adapters&hash=item4accef1441

in order to hook up my phone to the modem?

Comment: What about this cable? It appears to be an RJ-9 to RJ-11 cable.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/BLACK-Coiled-Handset-Cord-RJ9-plug-to-RJ11-plug-for-BT-IPC-Dealerboard-Headset-/380326162846?pt=Headsets&hash=item588d34b19e

Comment: @Generalkidd D'oh! I just realized that in my last two comments, I was only thinking about one direction of audio. So I deleted those comments. I still don't think the cables you've linked to will work, because you need a transformer between the telephone line and the audio jack. I think you'd need something like [this](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/284518-REG/JK_Audio_INLINE_InLine_Patch_Telephone.html), in addition to creating your own adaptor from that pair (one input, one output) of 3.5mm jacks on that box, to a 3.5mm phone headset plug.

Comment: @Spiff for completeness sake, could you add the online reference that stated the 2400 bps limit in your answer?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Sure, it was in [Wikipedia's article on CSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_Switched_Data): "Prior to CSD, data transmission over mobile phone systems was done by using a modem, either built into the phone or attached to it. Such systems were limited by the quality of the audio signal to 2.4 kbit/s or less." Although I note that this mention does not cite a source itself.

Answer (score 5):

Not a direct answer but a curious one.

While it is impossible to use legacy modems with cellular voice channels, it is, in fact, possible to design a specialized modem which will work over it (more or less by plugging into a handset jack, as OP desires). This is a useful feature, because:

1. Data coverage may not be available in the remote areas where data communications may still be required (to support ATMs and EFT terminals, to name the most common need).
2. Voice channel has highest communication priority and will keep operating even if data services are completely overflown (by a massive crowd or spike in usage).

IEEE article describing a possible approach:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4383352

Comment: There are other useful situations for this too. What I happen to be looking for is not to connect to the Internet, but rather to connect to and administer a legacy phone system (PBX).

Comment: [JackPair](http://www.jackpair.com), a dongle for voice call encryption for mobile phones, does precisely this.

Answer (score 2):

had previously connected a cell phone to analog modem, before data tethering was available.

used a cell phone dock that had connections for an external speaker and external microphone, and then used a heathkit ham radio phone patch to isolate (null)  audio in from audio out and provide a balanced telephone connection.

made a virtual phone line with filtered dc to make the modem happy, and connected the phone patch to it.

manually dialed the modem dial up number on the cell phone, had the modem connect with an atdt command that ignored lack of dial tone and dialed one digit.

this worked for many calls to a landline based modem

at the time 9600 baud was the norm, would think you could probably get 28,800 or 33.6k out of the setup

tried it with an ameritech (land line carrier) connected cell phone, the cell phone calls were echoed without the setup and would not do a connection at all with a modem

had another same model cell phone on cellular one (wireless carrier), the normal cell calls were crystal clear, when hooked to the "setup" it provided dial up modem calls from all around my state and nearby states, as well as long distance modem calls from outside the area

also had a normal desk phone so they could do test calls thru the setup, if there was a question about it working.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about converting your phones Data connection to the cell provider into a dial-up signal to input into dial up modem, this may be possible and would probably overcome most of the issues that others are talking about, if you were trying to use the cell phone as a dial up modem that would be a different story.

if you could figure out how to convert your data connection to the same signal you would still have to find a audio jack to phone line adapter and then plug it into a dial-up modem, in which you would only be able to achieve the data speeds of the Dial-up modem

Comment: Could I theoretically use a combination of these:

http://www.showmecables.com/product/iPhone-Telephone-Adapter-3-5mm-TRRS-Jack-to-RJ11-Plug-6-IN.aspx?utm_source=msn&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=(roi)+product+listing+ads&utm_term=23-108-005&zmam=49733141&zmac=6&zmas=1&zmap=23-108-005

http://www.ebay.com/itm/PC-Headset-to-Smart-phone-Adapter-Dual-3-5mm-to-3-5mm-New-/321265800257?pt=US_Audio_Cables_Adapters&hash=item4accef1441

in order to hook up my phone to the modem?

Comment: yes, I think so,  you would have to have the right software on your phone to translate the Data connection to the correct signal, and to take the input from the modem as well. I think the software thing is going to be the tricky part of the whole set up really.

Comment: What if I used a dialup program from the ISP like NetZero? I know what number the program will dial, so I can just dial that number first, then run the program. It will dial again, but that shouldn't make a difference, the call should still connect right?

Comment: it's not about the call connecting, I think you are still thinking of dialing into your phone. what I am thinking about is bypassing that and turning the headphone jack into a phone line that translates your digital data connection from your phone into analog signals and the other way around to transmit.  does that make sense?

Comment: Well in this case, I'm assuming there's no wifi available and no 3G/4G signals available either. All that's available is the ability to make phone calls. What I'd like to do in this case is use my phone to dial out to NetZero or some other dial up ISP and use the audio line to a USB modem to provide dial up internet service to my laptop or tablet.

Comment: then that would fall under Spiff's answer, @Generalkidd.

Answer (score -1):

14.4 kbs is the base speed of cellular networks and can usually be used for "free" on an active cellular account. many ways to do this...yrs ago I had a serial connection cable for my cell to plug into my laptop...14.4k was the speed about 1.5 k a sec on the net so slow but ok for email chat etc